# Is this design possible for FloatingActionButton in Android?

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button

I have design of floating action buttons[image: transparent background] here :

but I want to change it like this : [image: I have to change items to white background]

Is it possible to do it in Android with floating buttons , if yes , how? Here is my xml code (There is some problem can't share like code part so sharing image) :

[[image: FloatingMenu][3]]

Comment: Button :  <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/button_templates"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/logo_blue_transparent"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/primary_color"
                fab:fab_icon="@drawable/icon_sale_templates"
                android:visibility="gone"
                fab:fab_size="mini"
...

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: you have to write your custom fab